# Generate evenly space point geography along a linestring in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, gis, geospatial

I have the total number of poles in a location (a sample area) and the road geometry (linestring) of each road in the area. I can calculate the average distance between poles, I want to distribute these total number of poles evenly along the different roads (linestring). I see that ST_LINE_INTERPOLATE_POINT() can help me achieve this but I dont have this function in BigQuery.

Snippest of my road_table is attached here.

My approach is generate interpolated points along the road at regular intervals determined by the raio value that is calculated from array as show below:

```
SELECT road_geometry, ST_LINE_INTERPOLATE_POINT(road_geometry, ratio) AS  interpolated_points
FROM road_table, UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY (0,1, 1/(road_length/avg_dist_pole) AS ratio
```

Hoping to have an output of array of POINT Geography for each record.

But ST_LINE_INTERPOLATE_POINT is not in BQ.

What other approach can I use to achieve this, beside I am not certain if this is the best approach?

Comment: BigQuery got native ST_LINEINTERPOLATEPOINT now:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_lineinterpolatepoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery does not have `ST_LINE_INTERPOLATE_POINT` but it has [ST_LINESUBSTRING](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_linesubstring) which returns line sub-segment. If you take sub-segment from 0 to the given fraction, the end point of this sub-segment will be the point you need.

You can define `ST_LINE_INTERPOLATE_POINT` like

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION ST_LINE_INTERPOLATE_POINT(line GEOGRAPHY, fraction FLOAT64) 
RETURNS GEOGRAPHY
AS (
  ST_EndPoint(ST_LineSubString(line, 0, fraction))
);
```

And call it e.g.

```
SELECT ST_LINE_INTERPOLATE_POINT(
  ST_GeogFromText('LINESTRING(1 1, 10 10)'), 
  0.9
);
```

**Update:** BigQuery got ST_LINEINTERPOLATEPOINT now:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_lineinterpolatepoint

Comment: Thank Michael, this is great, solved the problem.

Comment: Please mark the reply as accepted answer, it helps other user find it